# .net C# opc-client

Tags: c#, .net, opc

I want to write opc client for server. And dont want use big libraries. can i do it witn .net libs? smth like adding reference to opcautomation? but i cant find it in vs2010.
thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in support for OPC in VS but there are various COM Automation servers and .Net Class libraries that you can reference from VS easily enough.

The OPC Foundation have their own [.Net API](http://www.opcfoundation.org/Downloads.aspx?CM=1&CN=KEY&CI=281&CU=5) which would be the first place I'd start and it doesn't seem to be very big either (I'm not sure what you mean with big libraries)?

Comment: whats the name of dlls? in vs, that i need to reference?

Comment: @eba: Yes, sorry, forgot you need to be a member to download those, if your employer is a member of the OPC foundation you should be able to download it, otherwise you have to use some other vendors libraries.

Answer (score 1):

On [codeplex](https://opcuaservicesforwpf.codeplex.com/) you can download the WPF UA library which has support for Visual Studio addins that allow drop in placement for UA items.
https://opcuaservicesforwpf.codeplex.com/